# zeros about Riemann Zeta function and some L-function

Tags: number-theory

The Riemann Hypothesis says that all non-trivial zeros for the Zeta function have $\Re(s)=1/2$.

What about the zeros for the following series?

(1) $\zeta(s)=1+\frac{1}{2^s}+\frac{1}{3^s}+\frac{1}{4^s}+\frac{1}{5^s}+...$

(2) $\zeta_{\mathcal{2}}(s) =1+\frac{1}{3^s}+\frac{1}{5^s}+\frac{1}{7^s}+\frac{1}{9^s}+...$

(3) $\zeta_{\mathcal{3}}(s) =1+\frac{1}{2^s}+\frac{1}{4^s}+\frac{1}{5^s}+\frac{1}{7^s}+...$

(4) $\zeta_{\mathcal{5}}(s) =1+\frac{1}{2^s}+\frac{1}{3^s}+\frac{1}{4^s}+\frac{1}{6^s}+...$

(5) ... ...

We should be able to find that they all satisfy the functional equation.

Clearly, we can see $\zeta_2(s) = (1 - 2^{-s})\zeta(s)$, etc. And we can see from $\zeta$ function has infinitely many factors $(1-p^{-s})^{-1}$, after analytically continued to all complex s, every of them contributing to zeros ($\Re(s)<1$), leading to RH.

My questions:

(1) How many zeros (non-trivial) are the same for the above series after analytically continuing to all complex s?

(2) If $\zeta$ has exact the same zeores (non-trivial, in critical strip) with $\zeta_2,\zeta_3, \zeta_4 ...$,  is it a "proof" that $\zeta_q=\sum _{n =1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{s}}, (q,n)=1$ has no Siegel zero?

Comment: Well, you know the zeroes of $1-2^{-s}$, right? So that tell you the relation between the zeroes of $\zeta$ and $\zeta_2$.

Comment: I mean the zeros of $\zeta_2, \zeta_3$.. after analytically continued. It says all of them have similar none-trivial zeros with $\Re(s)=1/2$

Comment: $\zeta_2$, after analytic continuation, has the same zeros as $\zeta$ has, and also has the zeros of $1-2^{-s}$. If you have formulas for $\zeta_3,\zeta_4,\dots$ similar to the one you have for $\zeta_2$, then you can find their zeros, as well.

Comment: Thanks! That make sense. Can you please clear another my naive question? Obviously, $\zeta_2, \zeta_3$ ... are Dirichlet L-function with $\chi$ as principal. How can zeros of $1-2^{-s}$ follow GRH? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Riemann_hypothesis

Comment: Trivially! The GRH, as summarized in the link you give, is a conjecture about zeros in the "critical strip" $0 < Re(s) < 1$. The zeros of the function $1 - 2^{-s}$ are all along the line $Re(s) = 0$, so the extra zeros that this factor contributes to $\zeta_2(s)$ are irrelevant to the GRH.

Comment: If $\zeta$ has exact the sames zeros with $\zeta_2, \zeta_3...$ etc, then is it a "proof" that all those $\zeta_p$, p is prime, (or extensively, $\zeta_q=\sum^\frac 1{n^s}$, where (q,n)=1), has no Siegel zero?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siegel_zero

Comment: what I mean is the zeros in 'critical strip'. Thanks.

Comment: David, Thanks for your answers! Can you please check my last question? Really appreciate it!

Comment: It is, but for Dirichlet L functions the only interesting case for non-existence of Siegel zeros is for real (thus quadratic) nontrivial character.

Comment: Thanks! It's interesting that different series have EXACT same zeros in 'critical strip' though.

Comment: So, what part of your question has not been answered?

Comment: Then maybe you could write up and post an answer incorporating what you now know. Then, later, you can accept your answer. This helps clean up the Unanswered Questions list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\zeta_q$ as defined in question, has exact the same zeros in critical strip $0<\Re(x)<1$.